# Insert separate each digit by a delimiter

Tags: vb.net

Textbox1.Text= you should delimited these digit with comma after each digit. so how do i do this?

```
227
72
13
492
```

Code:

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim pieces() As String = TextboxIndex1.Text.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim str As String = ""
    For Each piece As String In pieces
        str &= piece.Insert(piece.Length - 1, ",") & ControlChars.CrLf
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 3)
    'Get all chars
```

Output:

```
22,7
7,2
1,3
49,2
```

Expected Output:

```
2,2,7
7,2
1,3
4,9,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code only inserts a comma at the second last position. You can use `String.Join` to concatenate an array's elements with a given separator.

```
'On Error Resume Next    'Remove this
Dim pieces() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim str As String = ""

For Each piece As String In pieces
    str &= String.Join(",", piece.ToCharArray().ToList()) & ControlChars.CrLf
Next

TextBox2.Text = str
```

`piece.ToCharArray()` turns the `String` into a `Char()`. Unfortunately, we can't pass this straight to `String.Join` because the compiler sees the char array as a string. This is the reason for the `.ToList()` call.